# SQLite sqlite3_column_text return corrupt data

Tags: sqlite, mfc, sqldatatypes, c-strings, corrupt

I have tried strcpy, memcpy etc.. but unfortunately char data still corrupt after finalising sqlite. But nothing happens to CString data. I know that I have to copy the field into another one before finalise it but doesn't work.I am also not sure, if it is safe to use CString data instead.

```
    CString StrDescription;
    char dbDescription1[110+1];

    const char *data = NULL;
    char *SQLString= new char[SQLStr.GetLength()+1] ;
    memset(SQLString,0x00,sizeof(SQLString)-1);wcstombs(SQLString,SQLStr,SQLStr.GetLength());SQLString[SQLStr.GetLength()]='\0';
    if ( sqlite3_prepare_v2( db,SQLString , -1, &stmt, NULL )!= SQLITE_OK)
    {
       sqlite3_finalize( stmt ); sqlite3_close(db); delete[] SQLString; return -1;
    }
    delete[] SQLString;

    if( sqlite3_step( stmt ) == SQLITE_ROW ) 
    {       
        data = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text( stmt, 4 ); sprintf(dbDescription1 ,"%s",data); 
        StrDescription = CString(data);
    }    

    AfxMessageBox(CString(dbDescription)); // Result is ok here..
    AfxMessageBox(StrDescription); // Result is ok here as well.

    sqlite3_finalize( stmt );  sqlite3_close(db);

    AfxMessageBox(CString(dbDescription)); // Result corrupt here
    AfxMessageBox(StrDescription); // Result still ok 


    Thanks
```

Comment: What kind of corruption? How long is that column value?

Comment: it brings up only some part of data, sometimes nothing, but most of the time it is ok. and column is varchar(110)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that this is because StrDescription keeps a copy of the string, it still works after Sqlite is done cleaning up the memory that dbDescription1 points to. So yes using your CString is safe in this situation, and to be preferred over making copies in the C way (with strcpy/strncpy etc) in cases like this, because a string class (be it CString or std::string or another) will shield you from easy to make mistakes.

Comment: I have also tried to retrieve data as (char *) instead of (const char *) and did data[110]='\0';  and then sprintf(dbDescription1,"%s",data);   it looks like it works as I realised that I definately need data in char field rather than CString. But I am not sure now, if this way also safe or not !. Tha nk you.

Comment: It doesn't matter in what form you retrieve or store the data, the point is that using the CString makes a *copy*, whereas hanging onto the original pointer (the data which it points to being malloc'ed and managed by sqlite) will stop working once you shut down sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not check column limits, so it is possible that there are more than 110 characters.

Furthermore, in UTF-8, characters are not necessarily identical with bytes, so it is possible that there are more than 110 bytes.

Either use `sqlite3_column_bytes` or `strlen` to check how large a buffer you need to allocate, or just use a `CString` as buffer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think instead of checking all the fields with strlen , using CString is better. I just wasnt sure if it safe after having problem with char.